# Ruby, rvm and geokit gem. Trouble with UTF-8

Tags: ruby, utf-8, geokit

i use rvm, Ruby 1.9.3 and geokit(1.6.0) gem and have trouble with UTF-8.

i added line `export RUBYOPT=-Ku` to my ~/.rvm/environments/@default and replaced `exec ruby "$@"` with `exec ruby -Ku "$@"` in ~/.rvm/bin/ruby.
Then i'm tryed to execute File.rb with two strings:

```
require 'geokit'
a=Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode 'München'
```

Error:

ruby-1.9.3-p0@mygemset/gems/geokit-1.6.0/lib/geokit/geocoders.rb:443:in `do_geocode': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)

Why `export RUBYOPT=-Ku` and `exec ruby -Ku "$@"` dont work for geocoders.rb and work for File.rb?
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# encoding: UTF-8
require 'geokit'
require 'cgi'

a = Geokit::Geocoders::GoogleGeocoder.geocode(CGI.escape('München'))
```